# MS Office Add-In Installer in VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ms-office, office-addins

I wrote add-in for MS Office, and I try to create installer for this add-in. I have installed VS Installer project type and I have installer. IT's OK, but I can't find this add-in in MS Word.
I have read [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx)  about installers for add-in projects, but it's for different version of VS.

Can somebody tell me what i need do for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unfortunately** VS 2015 does not support this kind of installer.... MS has had the same with VS 2013 and added the installer to VS 2013 again after some "riots" of a lot of users. Main Problem is that you have to set the registry keys right, wich, IMHO, is quite difficult with installshield limited edition. By the way, install shield is not a MS product, but a product of flexera. 
If you have any possibility to switch back to VS 2013 I would recommend this to you, using the setup-project there.

 If you want to use installshield limited edition anyway, here´s how to:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xI36omxTsSw&hl&hl=en_US&fs=1&autoplay=1

Comment: Thank you so much. :)
I'll try to use installshield limited edition

Comment: One moment. installshield limited edition available for 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015 Professional Edition.

Comment: Ah, ok, what Version are you using? I have enterprise, professional and ultimate, as I´m a MSDN account user

Comment: I took a deeper look at the editions and can´t find any restrictions. Take a look over here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dn531020.aspx Just download installshield from flexera out of your VS and you are reday to go.

Comment: I´m so glad you asked this questionn which lead me to intensive investigations! Just go over here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9  and you are able to install the original  VS installer projects. Use this an there are many toturials especially for building addins! Mostly these tutorials are made for Office 2010, but creating the installer is just the same for 2013 and 2016. If this is what you wanted please mark this as an answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you. I resolve my issue with  installshield limited edition + VS 2015 enterprise edition.
Your answer really help me.

Comment: Hi, it's again me. Sorry i have one problem - i exe file and i can install my add-in in a computer, but when i go to the MS Word -> addIns -> i see name of my add-in, but ms word said, that my add-in is unloaded. What it can be?
If i uninstall add-in and after this launch vsto file it will be install successfully and it will work fine.

Comment: I have this problem only with MS Word 2007.

Comment: I´m not sure, because there are some informations missing. Maybe this could be a problem with your registy keys. Just post a new question with this problem an dsome more information (maybe screenshots etc.)